# ошибка IOException

Tags: java, android, json

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    EditText etEnterPassword;
    EditText etEnterLogin;
    Button btnEnter;
    CheckBox cbEnter;
    TextView tvChecking;
    Button btnChecking;
    private final static String DIRECTORY_NAME = "dataDir";
    private final static String FILE_MAIN_NAME = "contextFile";
    private final static String DIRECTORY_PATH = "./src/main/java/org/Council/context.txt";
    String data;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        etEnterLogin = findViewById(R.id.etEnter);
        etEnterPassword = findViewById(R.id.etEnterPassword);
        btnEnter = findViewById(R.id.btnEnter);
        cbEnter = findViewById(R.id.cbEnter);
        btnEnter.setOnClickListener(this);
        try {

            check();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "It's not OK(checkMain)", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            toast.show();
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void jsonWriter() throws IOException {
        File context = new File(DIRECTORY_PATH);
        File data = new File(context, FILE_MAIN_NAME);
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        if (!data.exists()) {
            data.mkdir();
        }
        if (!context.exists()) {
            context.createNewFile();
        }
        FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter(DIRECTORY_PATH + "/context.txt");
        gson.toJson(getDataLogin(), fileWriter);
        gson.toJson(getDataPassword(), fileWriter);

    }

    public String jsonReader() throws IOException {
        FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(DIRECTORY_PATH + "/context.txt");
        while (fileReader.ready()) {
            data = data + fileReader.read();

        }
        return data;
    }

    public void check() throws IOException {
        String check = jsonReader();
        if (check == "adminadmin") {
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "It's OK", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            toast.show();
        }

    }

    public String getDataLogin() {
        String login = etEnterLogin.getText().toString();
        return (login);
    }

    public String getDataPassword() {
        String password = etEnterPassword.getText().toString();
        return (password);
    }

    public void onClick(View view) {
        switch (view.getId()) {
            case R.id.btnEnter:
                try {
                    jsonWriter();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "It's not OK(jsonWriter)", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                    toast.show();
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                try {
                    check();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "It's not OK(check)", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                    toast.show();
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
        }
    }
}
```

приложение должно сохранять файл с логином и паролем, затем при открытии приложения или при вводе данных проверять пароль, если он совпадает с adminadmin писать "it's OK" Но вываливается ошибка

Comment: Лог ошибки, опубликованный в вопросе, может значительно ускорить решение проблемы. `./src/main/java/org/Council/context.txt` - это же не файл в проекте на ПК? Вы должны понимать, что ваше приложение выполняется на Андроид-устройстве, которому не доступны файлы в памяти компьютера, даже если приложение выполняется в эмуляторе.

Comment: в лог пишет W/System.err: java.io.IOException: No such file or directory

Comment: Почитайте про `assets` ([статейка по теме](http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/theory/assets.php)) и ресурсы - их нужно определять в специальных папках и читать определённым образом. Фалы в файловой системе телефона не появятся, пока вы сами их туда не запишете, и ещё раз повторяю: файлы ПК недоступны с телефона (вы же не думаете что все телефоны пользователей приложения получат доступ к файлам вашего компьютера? - думаю вы и сами этого не захотите).